# How to get the cursor position in a cell of QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget and I need to know the position of the cursor in a cell.

For QLineEdit there exists a function QLineEdit::cursorPosition( ).

Is there something similar for a cell in a QTableWidget or for a QTableWidgetItem?
Or any other method how I can find out the cursor position of the currentItem?

[image]

I hope it gets clearer with this picture. I have entered the cell item of row 27 and started to edit the cell item. The blinking cursor is between the second and the third Hallo. I want to find out at which position this blinking cursor is in the cell (same as for QLineEdit::cursorPosition)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'cursor' here.  Are you just looking for something like [`QTableWidget::currentItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentItem)?  If not then please clarify by providing some example code that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added an example picture. I hope it gets clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this method:

`QTableView::rowAt()` - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#rowAt

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think this can help me.